# Base class method with a generic object argument

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a MustInherit Class that represents a programmable pump in a generic high level representation.

Then I have a MustOverride Function SetupTimeProgram in this base class.

As I read from Overrides definition I have to have a “Matching Signatures. The signature of this declaration must exactly match the signature of the property or procedure that it overrides. This means the parameter lists must have the same number of parameters, in the same order, with the same data types.”

The argument of this function is the TimeProgram that I have to pass to the pump, but each pump has a different way to set its own time program. For this reason I cannot define at high level the type of the argument.

So I do in the base class:

```
Public MustOverride Function SetupTimeProgram(ByRef TimeProgram As Object) As Boolean
```

where TimeProgram is defined as generic object.

Then in each single implementation of SetupTimeProgram I do something like that:

Implementation-A

```
Public Overrides Function SetupTimeProgram(ByRef Program As Object) As Boolean
    Return DoSomething_A (Program.Time(), Program.Steps())
End Function
```

Implementation-B

```
Public Overrides Function SetupTimeProgram(ByRef Program As Object) As Boolean
    Return DoSomething_B (Program.Line(), Program.MaxPressure, Program.MinPressure)
End Function
```

In other word the argument is completely different in each implementation.

My goal is to create a generic SetupTimeProgram method in order to write the same code for all the pumps. In this way, who uses the class should be care only to pass the argument in the right way and format.

I am wondering if it is the right way to do that.

Comment: This question is better suited for the [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an interface for the parameter, putting the responsibilities of the `DoSomething_A` and `DoSomething_B` methods to the concrete class implementations.

```
Interface ITimeProgram
    Sub DoSomething()
End Interface

Class TimeProgramA : Implements ITimeProgram
  Public Property Time As DateTime 
  Public Property Steps As Integer

  Public Sub DoSomething() Implements ITimeProgram.DoSomething
      ' do something with the Time and steps properties
  End Sub
End Class

Class TimeProgramB : Implements ITimeProgram
  Public Property Line As String
  Public Property MaxPressure As Integer
  Public Property MinPressure As Integer

  Public Sub DoSomething() Implements ITimeProgram.DoSomething
      ' do something with the Line and min/max pressure properties
  End Sub
End Class
```

Then, instead of having an abstract (`MustOverride`) method, just implement it like

```
Public Function SetupTimeProgram(ByRef Program As ITimeProgram) As Boolean
   Return Program.DoSomething()
End Function
```

This way:

1. the user must pass a valid `ITimeProgram` into the method
2. the `ITimeProgram` instance must know how to `DoSomething`